# How to understand concepts like REST and AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I find it hard to properly understand how REST (ASP.NET Core API) and AngularJS come together. I also find hard to get what is the difference between a controller and an API.
I watched this video regarding ASP.NET Core Web Application:
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnetcore-efcore-bootstrap-angular-web-app/table-of-contents
The video shows how to create, for example, a pure html contact form, using ViewModel and attributes to validate it, server-sided.
Then, other module, shows how to create an AngularJS kind of form, and validate client-sided.
I find hard to understand why the validation should be client-sided (code dup...).
It seems to me like all the "power" of razor as C# language is replaced with Angular..?
I hope I explained myself properly.

Answer (score 3):

**Web API**

Provider of data.

The role of a web API is to simply provide data to consumers. Let's say you were building a blog and you would like to store all of the authors and blog posts in a SQL database. A major security flaw would be if you simply gave the browser (your clientside javascript) access to the database to start throwing blog posts in there willy-nilly. Instead, it's a common practice to put a server-side API in between the browser javascript and the backend SQL. This is where the API comes in. Your API simply sits in the middle, and knows how to retrieve blog posts, insert new blog posts, etc.

**Angular**

Displayer of data.

This is the browser javascript side. Now that we have an API sitting in between us and the database, all we need to do is know how to communicate with the API. When our page loads up, we can simply send a request off to the API that says something like: `var posts = RetrieveBlogPosts();`, and maybe `RetrieveBlogPosts` under the hood just sends an HTTP `GET` request off to our API at `http://localhost:8000/api/posts`. The API responds to an incoming request based off that route, and knows exactly which server-side method to step into. It then goes into the database, gets the blog posts, and sends them back to the Angular app running on the client's browser. The data it sends back is typically in a JSON format. Your Angular app will then receive the response (JSON), transform it into objects that represent blog posts, and then display that data in the browser (HTML templates/css/etc).

Comment: Hi. I'm familier with those major differences. Another question for example: Say I have customers and orders.
What part is responsible of the intergation (data manipulation)? - Finding the orders of customer A? the API? the Angular code?
The common sence says that the API, but then, every small thing will require approaching to the server, etc...

Comment: Would you want front-end JavaScript running in the user's browser to first get all orders and then filter to only the user's orders? That would mean anyone could access everyone's orders. Whenever something is not meant for the user, it should not leave the server. So in that case the API has to authenticate the caller and return the data they are allowed to see.

Comment: @juunas, I have edited my comment... but say after the auth succeeded.

Comment: Of course it is after authentication, but you still would not do filtering on client-side. I could just look at my F12 tools and grab every user's orders.

Comment: If we're talking about F12, is there a way to encapsulate the angular part?
say, not showing ng-repeat... but the finished result to the client.
Another way to ask this question - does Angular shows the user too much info?

Comment: Just note that validation should occur on both server and client side. People can fake the validation on the server, or just send HTTP requests to your server and directly bypass your UI.

Comment: You can't hide the clientside javascript from the user. You can obfuscate it (minimize/etc), but it's still running in the browser, so they can see it.

Answer (score -3):

As mariocatch already explained well about Api and Angular JS. I am going to put light on the question you have that why would be validation on the front end?That is entirely developed for the sake of performance. In big applications, performance matters alot. So instead of checking the validation conditions like

- email is in correct format
- password must be minimum 6 characters
- password must contain atleast 1 Capital letter
- password must contain at least 1 special character

Just think rationally, why would you want to involve server for all these validations. Now a days when websites have millions, billions of users, the server is not free to do these validations. So that is why validations are moved to client side. Yes that is replacing the C# razor power but that is obviously for the good performance of the web applications in the long run.

I think that clears your confusion about client side validations.

Comment: Server-side validations are always mandatory. Client-side validations are good for performance yes, but server-side validations must still be included. There is never a good reason to only do client-side validation. Programming 101 is that you do not trust user input.

Comment: I see, so, basically, the server-side will provide the API and then using Angular we will communicate with it.

Comment: I am not saying that server side validations should be excluded. If you use client side validation, you might want to validate information at server once only maybe before submitting the information. But that happens only when client passed through all the validations at client side and most of the time information is almost correct.

Comment: @NatanZB yes that is correct

Comment: To all downvoters. Please advice on the betterment of the answer as well rather than just downvoting.